# Firebase images to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, firebase, uicollectionview, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I need some guidance in populating my collection view with images from Firebase. I've searched stack, google and youtube but couldn't find a fix for my problem. The captions (or "description/ requestDescription as I've named them) are displaying correctly, but the images related to each is not. There are 3 unique photos in the Firebase database but only two of them appear in the collection view (all 3 appear when I print the snapshotValue to the console though). Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return requestDescriptionsArray.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cellID = "CollectionViewCell" 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    //grab all images from database
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "replies").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print(snapshotValue!)

        //get images
        let photoURL = snapshotValue?["photo"] as! String
        let url = URL(string: photoURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.photo.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }).resume()
    })

    cell.requestDescription.text = requestDescriptionsArray[indexPath.item] 

    return cell
}


func initForImages() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "replies").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print(snapshotValue!)

        //get descriptons and add to array
        let description = snapshotValue?["Description"] as! String
        self.requestDescriptionsArray.insert(description, at: 0)
        self.collection.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi! You are doing it wrong. You need to store both "photo" & "Description" in a dictionary of array rather than sending a Firebase request in every cellForItemAt Call. Another easy way to load images is to use the SDwebimage. You got it or should i give a detailed answer ?

Comment: @JennyJose a detailed answer would be great, plus then I can accept it as the answer!